# How to fix blurry text underline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, blur

Sometimes I am so lazy to make underlines by using **Line Tool**

And the **underline** on text function on Photoshop is a bit **blurry**

[image: How to fix blurry text underline ?]

**When I zoomed :**

[image: How to fix blurry text underline ?]

There is **2 pixels** *(like 1 pixel semi-transparent extra)*

Any trick or setting can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit > Free Transform tool. Zoom in (more than 200%) and use the up/down arrow keys to nudge the text by sub-pixel values until the underline go crisp. That's the only workaround I know.

Comment: Thanks, But seems like it extra work than `Line tool` for me :(

Comment: really? More work to just reposition the text than create a line in the right place with the right lenght, then have to fix it in case the text changes?

Comment: Anyway, your answer is a best solution I found :D

Answer (score 0):

If this is still in text format, check the setting that controls the text clarity on the toolbar. Try different settings from what you are currently using. It may be set to "smooth" and your text is soft in places. See the image below.

[image: Text aliasing settings]

Comment: technicaly this is correct; in reality it doesn't always affect the underline.

Comment: Try changing font size for example 17,20.

Comment: All the answers may be irrelevant, including mine, since underlining normally does not belong in typography. The URL underlining may be an exception on the Web. It is a copy editor's notation to have the "underlined" text italicized. In short, think why you want to underline the text, and if it needs to be distinguished try italics or bold; not to be used excessively in all the instances. Now, some typographers may join in the conversation.

Comment: The answers (including yours) are relevant, as the question is how to make it look crisp (which was expected to happen by default, since it's a 1-pixel line) and not about typography per se.